# Awk print if no match

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am using the following statement in awk with text piped to it from another command:

```
awk 'match($0,/(QUOTATION|TAX INVOICE|ADJUSTMENT NOTE|DELIVERY DOCKET|PICKING SLIP|REMITTANCE ADVICE|PURCHASE ORDER|STATEMENT)/) && NR<11 {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

which is almost working for what I need (find one of the words in the regex within the first 10 lines of the input and print that word). The main thing I need to do is to output something if there is no match. For instance, if none of those words are found in the first ten lines it would output `UNKNOWN`.

I also need to limit the output to the first match, as I need to ensure a single line of output per input file. I can do this with `head` or ask another question if needs be, I only include it here in case it affects how to output the no-match text.

I am also not tied to awk as a tool - if there is a simpler way to do this with sed or something else I am open to it.

Comment: have u considered using `if-else`? Something like -- `awk '{if ($0 == "your_match") {print "match"} else {print "no match"} }'`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but when I first looked at doing it this way it seemed like it would have two problems - first I end up with a "match" or "no match" for every line I touch, second I have to write out the full if-else for everyone one of the possible match words (those above are a subset of what will eventually be a very long list) - making it a monstrously long command. I may also just not understand what you are suggesting (and this is given that I would change the `if ($0 ==...` to `if ($0 ~ ...`)

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelley Yes. But you can adapt this for ur custom needs, like not printing, or doing other things as you need. But there are other ways to do this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to exit at the first match, or on line 11 if no match

```
awk '
    match($0,/(QUOTATION|TAX ... ORDER|STATEMENT)/) {
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        exit
    }
    NR == 11 {print "UNKNOWN"; exit}
'
```

Comment: that is perfect, also it kind of explains some of the syntax of awk that I have been not getting.. I think (`condition {action}`)

Comment: That's it exactly. If you omit the condition, the action will execute for every line. If you omit the action, the default is `print $0` if the condition is true. You'll sometimes see `awk 'condition {action} 1'` -- the trailing `1` is a shortcut for `{print}`

Answer (score 4):

I like [glenn jackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056120/970195) answer, however, if you wish to print matches for all 10 lines then you can try something like this:

```
awk '
match($0,/(QUOTATION|TAX ... ORDER|STATEMENT)/) {
    print NR " ---> " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    flag=1
}
flag==0 && NR==11 { 
    print "UNKNOWN"
    exit
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this..

```
( head -10 | egrep -o '(QUOTATION|TAX INVOICE|ADJUSTMENT NOTE|
   DELIVERY DOCKET|PICKING SLIP|REMITTANCE ADVICE|PURCHASE ORDER|STATEMENT)' 
    || print "Unkownn" ) | head -1
```